# I have a dedicated with 2 SSDs, how to I group them to behave as 1?

Tags: kernel, disk, fdisk

I have a dedicated server which I will use to build virtual machines on top of using KVM (thank you, Virtualizor), the problem is, I do not physical access to the machine as it is rented from a big company, and I need to figure out how to group the 2 storage to make them 1 volume, I can change the system if someone believes that one can be easier than other to manage the volume groups, I have this options of operating systems (that virtualizor supports and the dedicated provider allows:
CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 16.04(x86_64)
and the machine has 2 SSDs of 960GB

the problems I am facing (I am currently on CentOS 7) are:

1. as I am using one disk I don't know how to manage it while using it
2. the root has almost all space of one disk, which gives 60MB left
3. I have no idea how to set them in one single volume group

I believe I understood the part of the documentation on how to reduce the root size, but if you can more clearly describe the process, steps and what the steps do I sincerely appreciate.
So, if I can reduce the root size the only thing left will be to merge the 2 disks into one volume group, I have tried to extend it but I might have missed something IDK

```
[root@server]# fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 960.2 GB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00023b47

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
```

```
[root@server]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg   1   3   0 wz--n- 894.25g 60.00m
```

```
[root@server]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root  876G  3.0G  828G   1% /
devtmpfs              63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 63G  9.6M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                 63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1008M  143M  815M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp   976M  2.6M  907M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                 13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
```

```
[root@server]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               894.25 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              228928
  Free PE               15
  Allocated PE          228913
  PV UUID               kytvOh-HaSm-OOo3-l7OM-nbkk-QyQf-Mx1gCu
```

```
[root@server]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdb1   VG vg              lvm2 [894.25 GiB / 60.00 MiB free]
  Total: 1 [894.25 GiB] / in use: 1 [894.25 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

```
[root@server]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 960.2 GB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0001c70b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1875384319   937691136   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda: 960.2 GB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00023b47

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/vg-root: 954.8 GB, 954762002432 bytes, 1864769536 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-swap: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-tmp: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Do to want extend existing volume group or create redundancy ?

Comment: @mrc02_kr I want to extend, so instead of 2 960 I would have 1 volume that I can use and the volume would save on both disks. It is for personal use, so I will care about redundancy for data safety later, right now I am trying to glue to 2 into 1 volume so I can manage it easier

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do it to create new partition on `/dev/sda` device. Let's assume you will create `/dev/sda2`. You can do it using this commands:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
n - to create new partition
t -> 8e - to change partition type to Linux LVM
w - to write changes and exit
```

Then to have to let kernel know that new partition is created:

```
partprobe /dev/sda2
```

This commands will initialize `/dev/sda2` partition for LVM, and add them to existing volume group:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda2
vgextend vg /dev/sda2
```

Then you can extend existing logical volumes or create new ones using `lvextend` or `lvcreate`. You can create few types of Logical Volumes: linear, stripped, RAID. It's up to you how you will use your space.

If you choose to extend the existing LV you have to also resize filesystem (`xfs_growfs` or `resize2fs` for EXT). If you choose to create new LV you have to create filesystem on it using `mkfs` command.

Comment: thank you very much, I could indeed create one volume, tough, now on the Virtualizor panel I see only 893.31 GB available, I think this is because the root file system holds everything by itself, I saw a chart while reading about, I know the drives are empty, it is a fresh install, so, next question is, how to give more available space since it has but shows as not possible to use for some reason

Comment: Probably XFS reserved some space for inodes. You can read about it in many questions on unix.stackexchange

Comment: I am trying to shrink the root but I don't think it is possible while using it